# What parts do I need to get this outdoor light working?

Tags: lighting, outdoor

I'm sure I need a light bulb of some type, but I do not know what kind or what else I need.  I just bought my first house and I am a DIY rookie.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The holes in the white part look like they might fit a [G4-base halogen bulb](http://www.google.com/search?q=G4+base+halogen+bulb&tbm=shop):

[image: G4 halogen bulb]

It also looks like there is a label that's curling away from the side of the fixture in the lower photo; if so, it should have information on the maximum wattage that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from the picture if the lens assembly includes a reflector.   If it does, Niall C's answer is probably correct.   If not, an MR16 bulb includes a reflector and a similar bi-pin base.   Both types of bulbs are used in low-voltage landscape lighting.